# parse a json object in a div while scraping using beautifulsoup python

Tags: json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am learning scraping. I need to access the json string i encounter within a DIV. I am using beautifulsoup.
This is the json string i get in the DIV. I need the value (51.65) of the tag "lastprice". Please help. The JSON object is in json_d

```
import pip
import requests
import json 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print ('hi')

page = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=NBCC&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

json_d = soup.find(id='responseDiv')

print ('bye')
```

Comment: You need to do three things: 1) Find an element by its ID with Beautifulsoup. 2) Get the text of an element with Beautifulsoup. 3) Parse a string of JSON in Python. All of these things can be found out in less than 5 minutes. Please try on your own first.

Comment: I did it Tomalak, but I am stuck when I pass the extracted html. i.e: html = BeautifulSoup(extracted string). The error i get is : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bs4
import json

r= '''
<div id="responseDiv" style="display:none">{"tradedDate":"07DEC2018","data":[{"pricebandupper":"58.35","symbol":"NBCC","applicableMargin":"15.35","bcEndDate":"14-SEP-18","totalSellQuantity":"40,722","adhocMargin":"-","companyName":"NBCC (India) Limited","marketType":"N","exDate":"06-SEP-18","bcStartDate":"10-SEP-18","css_status_desc":"Listed","dayHigh":"53.55","basePrice":"53.05","securityVar":"10.35","pricebandlower":"47.75","sellQuantity5":"-","sellQuantity4":"-","sellQuantity3":"-","cm_adj_high_dt":"08-DEC-17","sellQuantity2":"-","dayLow":"51.55","sellQuantity1":"40,722","quantityTraded":"71,35,742","pChange":"-2.64","totalTradedValue":"3,714.15","deliveryToTradedQuantity":"40.23","totalBuyQuantity":"-","averagePrice":"52.05","indexVar":"-","cm_ffm":"2,424.24","purpose":"ANNUAL GENERAL MEETING\/DIVIDEND RE 0.56 PER SHARE","buyPrice2":"-","secDate":"7DEC2018","buyPrice1":"-","high52":"266.00","previousClose":"53.05","ndEndDate":"-","low52":"50.80","buyPrice4":"-","buyPrice3":"-","recordDate":"-","deliveryQuantity":"28,70,753","buyPrice5":"-","priceBand":"No Band","extremeLossMargin":"5.00","cm_adj_low_dt":"26-OCT-18","varMargin":"10.35","sellPrice1":"51.80","sellPrice2":"-","totalTradedVolume":"71,35,742","sellPrice3":"-","sellPrice4":"-","sellPrice5":"-","change":"-1.40","surv_indicator":"-","ndStartDate":"-","buyQuantity4":"-","isExDateFlag":false,"buyQuantity3":"-","buyQuantity2":"-","buyQuantity1":"-","series":"EQ","faceValue":"1.00","buyQuantity5":"-","closePrice":"51.80","open":"53.15","isinCode":"INE095N01031","lastPrice":"51.65"}],"optLink":"\/marketinfo\/sym_map\/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=NBCC&amp;instrument=-&amp;date=-&amp;segmentLink=17&amp;symbolCount=2","otherSeries":["EQ"],"futLink":"\/live_market\/dynaContent\/live_watch\/get_quote\/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=NBCC&amp;instrument=FUTSTK&amp;expiry=27DEC2018&amp;type=-&amp;strike=-","lastUpdateTime":"07-DEC-2018 15:59:59"}</div>'''

html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r)
soup = html.find('div', {'id':'responseDiv'}).text

data = json.loads(soup)

last_price = data['data'][0]['lastPrice']
```

EDIT:

```
json_d = soup.find(id='responseDiv')
```

Try changing to

```
json_d = soup.find(‘div’, {‘id’:'responseDiv'})
```

Then you should be able to do

```
data = json.loads(json_d)

last_price = data['data'][0]['lastPrice']
```

See if that helps. I’m currently away from my computer until Tuesday so typing this up on my iPhone, so can’t test/play with it.

The other thing is the site might need to be read in after it’s loaded. In that case, I think you’d need to look into selenium package or html-requests packages.

Again, I can’t look until Tuesday when I get back home to my laptop.

Comment: Thanks, it works when passed as a hard coded string; but when i scrap and pass the extracted html, it fails. ERROR: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: I know you’re new to stachoverflow, but that’s why you need to provide as much code as you can. I have no idea what you’re doing incorrectly because you haven’t specifically shared what you’ve done. Include how you’re scraping that. Show how you’re obtaining that. We can only work with what you give.

Comment: Also, take some time to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers chitown88, i am sharing my code:                                            import pip
import requests
import json 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print ('hi')

page = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=NBCC&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

json_d = soup.find(id='responseDiv')

print(json_d) 
#find last_value value from json_d

print ('bye')

Comment: Nice! Probably better to share it by editing your original post/question.

Comment: Done! I have just copy pasted the code in text. Sorry couldnt find the formatting for python.